# firebase.auth().currentuser reload throws a network error

Tags: firebase, expo

Getting `Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.` during authentication using `"firebase": "8.2.3"` installed with `expo install firebase`.

In my app I listen to incoming links during authentication once the continueUrl button is clicked after verifying the email, then I check if the currentUser email is verified:

```
const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (!currentUser?.emailVerified) {
  console.log("Email was not verified");
  currentUser?.reload().then(() => {
    console.log("Reloaded the user");
    if (currentUser.emailVerified) {
      console.log("Email was verified");
      setUser({ emailVerified: true });
    }
  });
}
```

The error is thrown by `currentUser?.reload()`
I can see the "Email was not verified" logged before it fails. I never see "Email was verified".
Also, this is random. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.
Happens in Expo Go as well as in production.

Answer (score 0):

You should deffinitely use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener to get the current user:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

The `firebase.auth().currentUser` doesn't always give what you expect because it needs to load the auth state first and you can call this only as synchronous code so it might happen what you see that it sometimes work and sometimes not.

Comment: OK, so I added a listener to `onAuthStateChanged`, but my user's authState is actually not changing. The user is already signed in and simply changes their email address. A verification link is sent, they click it, the email gets verified, and a continueUrl button is generated that opens the app. So the listener never fires anything since the authState hasn't changed.

Comment: The email will onyl be verified when the user clicks on the link. You can't await something like that.

Comment: I based my solution on this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html it will explain better what I'm doing. The only issue is that .reload() often fails.

Comment: How often do you try to relaod? Maybe you get blocked because of to much requests.

Comment: It's possible. I wouldn't be surprised since I am testing it now and doing this over and over. Anyway, I was hoping to use reload to do this right, but honestly, I will just change the state object of emailVerified to true and be done with it :) Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Maybe use a state like `emailVerificationSend` . That would show the state as it is. The user would have the `emailVerified` when reopening the app next time.